# Where was this object injected?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I'm learning Spring. In the following code, kafkaTemplate instance was not injected with @AutoWired in line 7. how can it be used in TransactionsListener method:

```
@Service
public class TransactionsListener {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory
        .getLogger(TransactionsListener.class);

    KafkaTemplate<Long, Order> kafkaTemplate;               // line 7
    AccountRepository repository;

    public TransactionsListener(KafkaTemplate<Long, Order> kafkaTemplate, AccountRepository repository) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @KafkaListener(
            id = "transactions",
            topics = "transactions",
            groupId = "a",          
            concurrency = "3")                  

    @Transactional("kafkaTransactionManager")   
    public void listen(Order order) {
        LOG.info("Received: {}", order);
        process(order);
    }

    private void process(Order order) {/*...*/}
```

Comment: What error is coming?

Comment: There is no error. Just wondering why no injection is needed for it.

Comment: the code was from: https://piotrminkowski.com/2022/10/29/kafka-transactions-with-spring-boot/

Comment: You don't need to explicitly annotate with `@Autowired` when injecting via constructor. The AccountRepository gets autowired the same way as well.

Comment: @Slevin: thanks. I think that is the reason. (As of Spring 4.3, there is implicit injection)

Comment: FYI, 4.3.x and earlier are no longer supported; the oldest supported version (OSS) is 5.3.x. https://spring.io/projects/spring-framework#support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring will automatically inject beans that are constructor parameters. `@Autowired` is not required.

Such beans must exist and be unique, or exactly one must be marked `@Primary`, or one of the dependency bean's name must match the parameter name.

Comment: To be more precicesly, Spring will automatically inject `Beans`. So Spring has to know about these Objects, otherwise autowiring wouldn't know what to inject. Just 1.2 cent ;)